# TempusDominus v5.1.2 for Bootstrap 4 - how _viewDate is set?

Tags: jquery, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I'm trying to understande the Tempus Dominus Bootstrap4 v5.1.2 code to make some changes and tests but I dont understand how the var _viewDate is set when the user pick the date.

When the user clicks on the day the function TempusDominusBootstrap4.prototype._doAction is executed with the 'selectDay' case (https://github.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/blob/master/src/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js#L690).

At this point the selected date is already on this._viewDate, but how? where was it set?

Thank you.

Comment: In line 919 : https://github.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/blob/master/src/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js#L919

Comment: this line is not called when I click to select day :S